# Too many query rows exception during Data load

Tags: apex, soql, governorlimits, limitexception

We have a trigger on a parent object where we query the child records for newly inserted/updated parent records. We are getting too many soql exception when more than 50K parent records are loaded. We cant suggest to load less than 50K. Is there a way to handle this exception?

below is my trigger

```
 trigger ParentTrigger on parent__c(before insert,after insert,before update,after update,before delete,after delete,after undelete) {
   if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
            ParentTriggerHandler.approvalService(Trigger.oldMap.keySet());
    }
    
}
```

below is my handler class

```
public class ParentTriggerHandler {
    public static void approvalService(Set<Id> parentIds){
        List<Child__c> childList = [SELECT id  from Child__c where parent__c in:parentIds]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What tool are you using to data load?

Comment: I guess its Data lake with salesforce connector

Comment: How can there be any child records if you have just inserted the parent records?  Please [edit] your post to clarify and include more details about the objects involved and what else is happening in the triggers.

Comment: There is already an existing functionality to create a child record as soon as parent is created with a master-detail relation to parent. Most of the data is stored and processed in child record. @DavidCheng